# Bind data.frames at specific depth of a list in R

Tags: r, data.table, purrr

Suppose I have a list with more depths. I want to extract all elements of a specific depth.

Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
Data <- as.data.table(mtcars)
splitvariables <- c("am", "gear", "carb")
for(i in 1:length(splitvariables)){
  Data <- map_depth(Data, .depth = i-1, .f = split, by = splitvariables[i])
}
```

Now `Data` is the following (it's only a part of it):

```
$`1`
$`1`$`4`
$`1`$`4`$`4`
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2:  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

$`1`$`4`$`1`
    mpg cyl  disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 22.8   4 108.0 93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2: 32.4   4  78.7 66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
3: 33.9   4  71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
4: 27.3   4  79.0 66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1

$`1`$`4`$`2`
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
2: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Now I have nested lists and all I want is to bind these `data.table`s like I would do it with `rbindlist` if these `data.table`s were not at that deep depth. I think there has to be a solution with only one line of code?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:-

```
a <- rbindlist(unlist(unlist(Data, recursive = FALSE), recursive = FALSE))
```

And `a` will just be one `data.table`.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know the `recursive` argument. That's my general solution: `for(i in 1:(length(splitvariables)-1)){
  Data <- unlist(Data, recursive = FALSE)
}
Data <- rbindlist(Data)`

Comment: @TobiSonne If you make assignments to unindexed data objects in a for loop, they will be overwritten in each of the succeeding iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different solutions to solve this problem:

#### Solution 1: based on `<<-` assignment operator

Let assume that the `data.frame`s are at depth 3 as in the example. Given that this depth is fixed,
you could combine the `map_depth` in the purrr package with an anonymous function (see below, inside `fun1`). Each time the anonymous function is called, the data.frame
passed to it is assigned to a list object, `l`, in the parent environment (hence the use of `<<-`). The variable `i` allows to increase the list.

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

fun1 <- function() {
  i <- 1L
  l <- list()
  map_depth(Data, 3, function(d) {l[[i]] <<- d; i <<- i + 1L})
  rbindlist(l)
}

fun1()
#      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#  1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#  2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#  3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#  4: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#  5: 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#  6: 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#  7: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#  ...
```

#### Solution 2: based on recursive function.

This solution works even if the depths of different *branches* in the nested list containing the data.frames are not fixed; but it requires that all the innermost lists be data.frame(s) (Remember that a data.frame is a list object). Also, note that this constraint can be easily relaxed.
In the code below, the value `3` in the `while` loop is not the depth of the nested list of data.frames but the depth of the typical list of data.frames passed to
`rbindlist` function (example: `vec_depth(list(mtcars, mtcars))` is 3).

```
fun2 <- function(x) {
  while(vec_depth(x) > 3) {x <- unlist(x, FALSE, FALSE); fun2(x)}
  return(x)
}

rbindlist(fun2(Data))

#      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#  1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#  2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#  3: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#  4: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#  5: 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#  6: 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#  7: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#  ...
```